# What would prevent the installation of windows on the roof of an airliner?

Tags: aircraft-design, windows

What prevents airline manufacturers from putting a strip of glass along the roof of the aircraft? It would be a good addition in terms of cabin view, light inside the cabin, etc.

Would it compromise the structural integrity too much?

[image]

Edit: The image is for representational purposes only. My question does not pertain to a installation similar to this image

Comment: I [read somewhere](http://www.aerospace-technology.com/contractors/interiors/vision-systems/pressdassaults-new-falcon-5x-smart-skylight.html) dassault aviation do it on the falcon 5X. This may be a natural evolution of [increasing windows size](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16862/what-are-the-factors-behind-increasing-aircraft-window-sizes).

Comment: Ironically, the picture you posted is for a [*windowless* aircraft concept](http://www.bloomberg.com/bw/articles/2014-09-18/technicons-ixion-jet-concept-is-windowless-with-a-view), where screens replace windows completely. That seems like a much easier way to give passengers an all-around view than dealing with the structural issues of huge gaps in the fuselage.

Comment: That's all good and neat and all, but oh my god, I would wager way more people would experience vertiginous gastronomical expulsions than desired.

Comment: Even with highly reflective glass, it would get uncomfortably hot in the cabin.  The idea is to get sunburn on the beach after you arrive, not in a plane on the way there.  No flying greenhouses for me.

Comment: I know that aquariums hold back massive amounts of water pressure with glass, but that glass is massively thick. How in the world would you pressurize an all-glass hull like that with glass thin enough to get it off the ground, and how would it take all the stresses of take-off and landing?

Comment: @FreeMan Aquaria are also are withstanding pressure on the convex side of their arch/cylinder structures, as opposed to on the concave side.

Comment: `vertiginous gastronomical expulsions` - @CGCampbell, that is quality word smithing right there!

Comment: @Pondlife: Your observation is correct, hence I have put a disclaimer that the picture is representational. However, on the concept of screens, I wonder, if they are going to show the actual view outside or a rendered image. If its a real time image, I would worry about video lag, which might have serious repurcussions on the passengers, watching jittery images all around.

Comment: @FreeMan: The same way windows work in an aircraft

Comment: @Firee, until reading the link provided by Pondlife about _windowless aircraft_ , I thought the intention was that the majority of the hull would be glass. _That_ would be incredibly heavy as the glass would have to provide all the structural support for the entire aircraft. The windows on a standard airliner simply have to resist air pressure, not provide mechanical support.

Comment: Quite apart from structural engineering issues, most people just don't want to look out the windows.  I recall one trip a decade or so ago (before I gave up commercial flying).  Denver to Reno, at night, with a full moon over a cloud deck and whispy streamers of cloud reaching well above our altitude.  Honestly looked like one of those fantasy illustrations, only missing a few unicorns.  Only people that saw it were me and a kid a couple of rows ahead: everyone else was happily watching old TV game shows.

Comment: Sweet, windowless aircraft... to solve the "vertiginous gastronomical expulsions" issue, provide each seat with a VR headset instead - passengers prone to motion sickness can simply forego their use, and those who do use them would get a far more awesome perspective.

Comment: @jamesqf I am just the opposite, but I can probably count the total number of flights I have made in my life on two hands.  Not having a window seat is always distressing to me as I love to watch what's going on, and people who have a window seat and then decide they are going to shut the window (so I can't even get a peek out) are even more frustrating! (I just don't have the gall to ask such people if they would trade seats with me...) In line with this, I am probably in the vast minority of people who would be happy if the just side and *bottom* of the plane was mostly glass.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, or the cabin attendants who insist you shut your window so that people can see the movie :-(

Comment: @MartinJames: having flown gliders a lot, I can tell you that even on the hottest days of summer it is kind of cold already at about 2000m above ground. At commercial jet levels, I would be really surprised if the greenhouse effect wins over the -50C on the other side of the glass.

Comment: There's probably not a very interesting view out of the top of an airliner, unless something has gone horribly wrong...

Comment: @ManuH I thought of the same thing when I saw this, although they are calling it a skylight:  [Dassault’s New Falcon 5X Feature An SPD-Smart Skylight](http://www.smartglass.com/full/dassaults-new-falcon-5x-feature-an-spd-smart-skylight/)

Comment: I thought this was about installing the Windows operating system on the roof of an aircraft. That'd be a little more challenging.

Comment: @etherealflux Its been done on ships - [Software glitches leave Navy Smart Ship dead in the water](http://gcn.com/Articles/1998/07/13/Software-glitches-leave-Navy-Smart-Ship-dead-in-the-water.aspx) - I really wouldn't want to replace 'water' with 'sky' in that title.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: That is an excellent insight... It would indeed be quite cold out there, else passengers would have been burnt already from the rays coming through the normal windows...

Comment: it's been done: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratospheric_Observatory_for_Infrared_Astronomy#/media/File:SOFIA_with_open_telescope_doors.jpg

Answer (score 25):

There are a few factors involved in this and you should check out [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16862/what-are-the-factors-behind-increasing-aircraft-window-sizes) that touches on window size (same issue really). For what its worth the ceiling is prime real estate on an aircraft. Modern airliners have the over head baggage compartments there (which provide a remarkable amount of space)

[image]

The area is also used to run cabling (electronics mostly these days) fore and aft as well as power to the reading lights etc. However it should be noted that these things could most likely be routed along the floor just as well.

The real issue comes back to windows being a weak point and glass being heavy. When it comes to planes you want them to be as light as can be so excess windows will only reduce useful load and increase potential failure points. On top of all that you will have more ambient light in the plane which may bother those trying to sleep on late night flights.

If you want a better view fly an unpressurized plane!
[image]

While on the topic of small bubble canopy planes, anyone that flies GA planes (especially like the ones shown above) with out air conditioning will tell you how hot it gets on the ground (and even at lower altitudes flying) in the summer. The canopies make the inside of plane behave like a green house and really heat up. This would make the inside of a jumbo jet really bake in the summer while taxiing (which can be a long process at big airports).

Comment: For a second (while still reading the text above) I though the yellow plane was a model that was somehow balanced on the windshield of the white plane...

Comment: I don't know about GA, but a C-130 gets ridiculously hot on the ramp, despite having basically no windows in the cargo compartment. Running the A/C helps a bit, but there's only so much it can do.

Comment: If glass is heavy, i am sure other composites could be used... If the windshield glass in front of the pilots can take the pressure, i am sure glass on the roof can handle it too.. Also, it need not be a huge area of glass, a thin strip would also do...

Answer (score 18):

The same thing that prevents them from just having glass down the entire length of the fuselage, rather than discrete windows: the ribs of the frame.

This picture from [cpast's answer on UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/73296/44852) shows how the windows are placed relative to the frame:

[image: Fuselage section frame]

On smaller aircraft, they probably could install small windows like the ones beside the passengers in the roof of the aisle, but it would add design complexity and also heat up the cabin (especially when sitting around on the ramp.) I'm assuming the cost/benefit ratio there was just deemed not worthwhile. Having them directly above the passengers wouldn't work because that's where the overhead storage bins are.

In the case of wide-body aircraft (like the one picture above,) note that the actual top of the fuselage is quite high. In addition to the overhead storage bins above the passengers, there is often other stuff between the ceiling of the passenger cabin and the actual top of the fuselage, such as crew rest quarters, pipes, cables, or, in the cases of the 747 and the A380, another entire passenger cabin.

An additional problem with this is that it would make it harder to control cabin lighting, unless the windows were electrically dimmable, like the new ones on the 787. Longer flights will usually want the passenger cabin to be dark-ish in order to accommodate the passengers who want to sleep. With the windows beside them, passengers can open or close their window depending on how much light they want. That wouldn't work for windows in the ceiling (since they would affect multiple rows of passengers.)

#### Further Reading

Window size limitations are also discussed in [Why aren't airliner windows aligned with their seats?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16847/755) and [the previously-linked question on UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/73296/44852).

Answer (score 10):

One other consideration is that the crown of the fuselage is under significant tension*, and glass does not have appreciable tensile strength.

*Think of the fuselage as a tube being held up midway along its length (i.e., by the wing). The weight of the fuselage and its contents will cause bending about the center wing box, putting the crown in tension, the keel in compression, and the sides under shear. The shear can be channeled around the window frames but normal loads would require far more structure for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The structural arguments have already been discussed, but a further thing to consider is that there really is no point.

For the small windows on airliners (necessarily small for the structural reasons outlined) the only person who gets a decent view is the person in the window seat, who has a wide angle view by virtue of being right next to the window.

The person in the aisle seat (or the centre block of a widebody) is lucky if they catch a glimpse of land out of the window.

A window on the ceiling of an airliner, besides being to far from anyone to give anyone a decent view, would be be pointing straight up at the sky. All you would see would be blue sky, cloud (under certain weather conditions while below cruise height) and blazing hot sun.

I recently flew from London to Guanzhou, China, on a 787, on which the designers made the appalling high-tech decision of using dimming windows instead of traditional shutters. The windows don't dim all the way to black, and the sun shining through the window is a real distraction when you're trying to sleep. Who would control the shutters on roof windows in an airliner?